# Highcharts Graph from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm trying to create a line graph from JSON data, with a horizontal line showing "temp1" and "temp2" for "serie1".

[This is my JSON File [TreeView]](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb2a7451)

My code what I've tried so far:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9uf85ac3/1/)

Please note that the json file is generated locally via an XAMPP server. You can view a copy of a generated one above with the 'TreeView'.

```
alert(data[0].name);
```

returns: "serie1" => As expected.
But it cant seem to parse the data to highcharts correctly.

Comment: please review your fiddler, doesnt work

Comment: as I mentioned above, the data is collected from a local XAMPP server. But even WITH the data it does not show any line whatsoever. You can view the data @ the TreeView link

Comment: use your json in fddle

Comment: shortened version of the json: https://jsfiddle.net/9uf85ac3/4/

Comment: Your data isn't in a format that Highcharts understands.  See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.data.  It has no way of knowing that 'date' is your xAxis and 'temp1' is your yAxis.  You'll need to preprocess your data to get it into one of the formats that Highcharts understands